# Animals in the Old Testament

Tags: genesis

When God told Abram to bring a she goat of three years old and a heifer of three years old and a ram of three years old, how did Abram know the ones he chose to take was “three years old” - See Gen 15:19.

Answer (score 1):

Just like modern farmers, Abram or the person in charge of his herds might have kept track of when each of his animals was born.

He would also have been familiar with how animals appear at various ages.
A three year old looks very different from a one year old, just as with humans.
Most of the animals would have been born in the spring, so there would be significant gaps between the animals in each age group, making it even easier.

And an animal's age can be estimated fairly accurately by other means.
For example here's [how cattle's teeth change with age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle_age_determination):

- 12 months - All the calf teeth are in place.
- 15 months - Centre permanent incisors appear.
- 18 months - Centre permanent incisors showing some wear.
- 24 months - First intermediates up.
- 30 months – Six broad incisors up.
- 36 months – Six broad incisors showing wear.
- 39 months – Corner teeth up
- 42 months – Eight broad incisors showing wear

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.

Comment: @curiousdannii, it's not marked as off-topic.  No one had responded to it for 10 hours.  If it explicitly referred to Genesis 15:9, would it then be on-topic?  Shouldn't someone post a comment on the question letting the OP know what is wrong with it?